# How to make the eigenvalues and eigenvectors stay real instead of complex?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, complex-numbers, eigenvalue

I try to diagonalize a `n*100*100` 3d matrix `K` by `numpy.linalg.eig` and get the eigenvalues `w` and eigenvectors `v`. The matrix is `100*100`, but I wanna do it with broadcasting, and that's the number `n` I set up. And the matrix is not hermitian.

```
w,v=np.linalg.eig(K)
```

At first, I tried `n=1000`, I get real eigenvalues and eigenvectors, i.e. `xxxxxxxxxe+xx`, but when I tried `n=2000`, the elements of `w` and `v` shows `xxxxxxxxxe+xx+0.j`. Due to `+0.j`, it gave complex numbers when using `w` and `v` do further calculation.

1. I thought it's because of the algorithm error for float number calculation but why?
2. Does numpy.linalg use LAPACK? Is that possible the error from LAPACK?
3. How can I get rid of `+0.j`?

Comment: Is the matrix symmetric/hermitian? How do you know it has real eigenvalues?

Comment: good question, I'm also trying to figure it out. It's not hermitian, but without broadcasting, only to diagonalize one `100*100` matrix always gives real eigenvalues and vectors. On if I diagonalize the 2000 `100*100` matrices in the same time, it shows the `+0.j` imaginary part.

Comment: If the imaginary part is zero then why don't you use `output.real`?

Comment: `+0.j` means the imaginary part of eigenvalues are 0 ? Or it just means they're complex numbers ?

Comment: You can try to toggle the printed precision by using [numpy.set_printoptions()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html). Due to the finite precision of double, a very small, not significant, imaginary part could be hidden behind `0.j`. You can dicard it by using `numpy.real`. To check that dropping the complex part is not damaging the eigenvector v and eigenvalue w, you can compute the norm of a residual `||w v - K.v||` and compare it to the norm `||v||`.

Comment: Thx, yes, the imaginary part is negligibly small, but I don't why when I try large `n`, it starts to show imaginary part. Is the error form LAPACK?

Answer (score 3):

According to documentation, `numpy.linalg.eig` uses (for real arguments) the LAPACK routine [DGEEV](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d9/d8e/group__double_g_eeigen_ga66e19253344358f5dee1e60502b9e96f.html#ga66e19253344358f5dee1e60502b9e96f) which does not make any assumptions about the input matrix (apart from being real). If the matrix is within floating point precision sufficiently symmetric, the complex part of the returned eigenvalues will be zero (the output argument `WI` of `DGEEV`). However, due to finite precision, it might happen that you could get some spurious complex parts.

EDIT:

1. If you are sure that your matrices have only real eigenvalues, you could strip the complex part with [`numpy.real`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.real.html) or use [`numpy.linalg.eigh`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eigh.html) specialized for symmetric matrices.
2. As for `numpy.linalg.eig`, the relevant part in `numpy/linalg/linalg.py` is:

   ```
   w, vt = _umath_linalg.eig(a, signature=signature, extobj=extobj)

   if not isComplexType(t) and all(w.imag == 0.0):
       w = w.real
       vt = vt.real
       result_t = _realType(result_t)
   else:
       result_t = _complexType(result_t)
   ```

So the test is a strict comparison `all(w.imag == 0.0)` and only then are the eigenvalues cast to real with `w = w.real`.

Comment: thx, I'm solving a matrix differential equation. `+0.j` means the imaginary part of eigenvalues are `0`?